# How do I make something I click fade out and in before it goes to another website linked in the page?

Tags: javascript, json, fadein, fade

So I'm coding this website and I what I want it  to do before it changes to another website that I linked to the whole page is fade out. And when it's finally in the website, it fades in.

Does anybody know the code to this?

Comment: This is pretty difficult to do well since you don't know how long the linked website will take to load until it's done. To approximate it with a set animation time, you could do something with setTimeout()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a css animation for your fade-out and then use `setTimeout()` in js to delay the process and navigate to a new page via js after the animation is done
(instead of `<a>` tag)

```js
function navigate(){

    const element = document.querySelector('.otherWebsite');
    element.classList.add('animation'); // setting the animation class to the element

    setTimeout(() =>{
        location.assign('https://stackoverflow.com')
    } , 3000) // delaying the process of the navigation for 3s (3000ms)

}
```

```css
.otherWebsite{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}
.animation{
    animation: fadeout 3s linear 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="otherWebsite" onclick="navigate()">Click here</div>
```

**Note:** You can also make the js function flexible for multiple tags using `data-href` or your preferred data set

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-href]').forEach(element =>{  // looping though all tags with 'data-href' in the page
    // setting an onclick event listener for the element
   element.onclick = () =>{
       element.classList.add('animation') // setting animation class to element
       const link = element.dataset.href || element.getAttribute('data-href'); // getting the link from the 'data-href' attribute
       setTimeout(() => location.assign(link) , 3000) // navigate to a new website after 3s (3000ms)
   }

})
```

```css
.otherWebsite{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.animation{
    animation: fadeout 3s linear 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
     opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="otherWebsite" data-href="https://stackoverflow.com">Website (stackoverflow)</div>
<div class="otherWebsite" data-href="https://google.com">Website 2 (google)</div>
```